# In a single query how to get feeds and also the information about which feeds have been liked by the logged in user

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (f:Feed)
WHERE f.feedType = 'sports' 
RETURN f 
order by f.timeAdded desc 
SKIP 4 LIMIT 10
```

I have User node and Feed node. I want to retrieve feeds related to sports with pagination. For that I have written the query as above. But with this I also need to know about which resulting feeds have been liked by the logged in user. Suppose I have a user with username john, how would i add [:LIKE] relation to the above query to get additional information about user-feed LIKE relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by matching your user and expand the pattern with `OPTIONAL MATCH` after the pagination :

```
MATCH (john:User {name:'john'}), (f:Feed)
WHERE f.feedType = 'sports' 
WITH john, f 
order by f.timeAdded desc 
SKIP 4 
LIMIT 10
OPTIONAL MATCH (john)-[r:LIKED]->(f)
RETURN f, count(r)
```

This will return you 0 if john not liked the feed, 1 if he liked along with each feed

Comment: Thanks a lot Christophe. It was the right and appropriate answer.

Comment: I am stuck in a problem related to the same. I am using SDN 3. Retrieving the result using query in GraphRepository class. I changed return type form Page<Feed> to Iterable<Map<String, Object>> and got IllegalStateException stating that return type can only be Slice, List or Page. What should i do now?

Comment: How should I retrieve the result now, Since now it has 2 columns.

Comment: unfortunately I can't help you that much about sdn3, you'll better open a dedicated question.